# How to stop Excel code from Matching certain formula fields and come back as true even though it is not correct (with example Spreadsheet)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have an issue I have a few field, player positions and it is partly working. in my table it is matching the correct field but also incorrect fields.

I have created a small excel sheet to explain what I am trying to do?:

**https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11IDOjUskH4uc6ZXJnoCI8eYUtLoxFjiO/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116676656825040438826&rtpof=true&sd=true**

In an ideal chase what should happen:

I have attached a spreadsheet which hopefully explains things clearly but in short, I am trying to figure out why if I have the data:

**M (L), AM (LR), ST (C)**

Why Does:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AM*C",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C3,"(",""),")",""))), "Yes", "No")
```

Say it is YES even though it should be NO, as the position AM (C) is not in the Input field?

Same goes for:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("M*C",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C3,"(",""),")",""))), "Yes", "No")
```

Why does this show as true even though M (C) is not there?

Can Anyone please help me? I think the spreadsheet explains this better then I sorry!

Comment: Why you are using asterisk `*` in formula? Any specific reason. You can directly use `M(C)`.

Comment: I think you really mean `?` instead of `*`. As the Asterix is a wildcard for any (multiple) characters that may come in between. Question mark is for a single character.

Comment: Then again. Your substitutes remove all characters in between and therefore the wildcard is not needed at all.

Comment: It returns `TRUE` because you are not searching for `M (C)`.  You are searching for `M*C`  (after removing the `()`'s),which means `M` followed by any number of characters followed by `C`.  Use the formula evaluator tool to better understand what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tested this and it does work, however when i replaced the * with a ? under the RWF position it went from Y to a N which is incorrect.. the reason is because is a the line starting AM LR and  I think because the L is  before the R it is ignoring that one... this is what I had in one of my tests but I am getting closer... The problem is in the brackets I can have any combination  of (LRC) that is  what makes the code a bit tricky for me....

Comment: I got a bit further:

For the AMC position at least:

       `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AM?C",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"(",""),")",""))),2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AM??C",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"(",""),")",""))),2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("AM???C",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"(",""),")",""))),2,"No")))`

Now I am only struggling with the MC Position...

Comment: Why not drop the 2 substitutes and search for `AM?C`?

Comment: I will test that thanks!, Now i need to get the last positions (M (C), (M (L), M (R) towork and ensure it does not pickup AM (L) or AM (R), AM (L) then I am done finally :D